# Adding StringFormat for Date only from a DateTime to Xaml textblock in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetime

So I'm using following code to pick up the datetime from my database:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DayOfEvent}" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FFD3D1D1"></TextBlock>
```

This gets the date-time info and displays it in the 3rd column. This is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsu4k.jpg .

How do I only get the date displayed, with the time "12:00:00 AM" removed? I think I'll have to use a StringFormat somewhere but haven't done it in this context yet and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DayOfEvent, StringFormat=hh:mm:ss tt}"/>
```